# What's the difference between a distribution list and a listserv?

Tags: email, mailing-lists

We have both where I work, and often times people are unsure which is appropriate for what. So my question is, what are the key differences between an email distribution list and a listserv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real difference that I am aware of is that a fully implemented ListServ provides the end user the ability to opt in or out of the list via email. A DL is typically more centrally managed and the users request that an administrator add or remove them from a DL. It's kind of funny since that central management nightmare is pretty much why ListServs were created and now most large businesses have email admins who spend significant time managing DLs.

Answer (score 2):

ListServ means the user can choose whether they'd like to receive the emails or if they'd like to leave the group (it's manually managed by the individual users).

A DistList is where the administrator adds or remove the people who will receive the emails.  So its manually managed by the administrator.

^^^
I'm pretty sure this is the only difference as my workplace also uses these two lists.

Hope this helps.